# Ruby on Rails: Image did not appear on Facebook Wall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, facebook

I am implementing the following server code to post image to facebook wall

```
current_user.mygraph.put_wall_post("Added to XXXX:",{
      :picture=> (answer.image.url ? answer.image.thumbnail : "http://dailymus.es/images/d_logo.png"),
      :link=>"XXX",
```

If the image thumbnail exists, everything works properly and I was able to see the image posted on the facebook wall (see screenshot)

[image]

However, if the image thumbnail does not exist, the picture to be posted should come from the url (in this case it is http://dailymus.es/images/d_logo.png) but nothing is displayed on the wall. I tried to paste the url in the browser and I was able to see the image in the browser. On the facebook wall, all I saw was a single grey vertical line.

[image]

Can anyone advise me on what could be the cause and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I work on the Developer Support team at Facebook. Sorry, it looks like we need to update our [Post documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to explain more about how to create a post. We'll do that ASAP.

When you include a "link" parameter, the way we get the image to show in the feed is by scraping your page (User Agent: "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)") for an [og:image tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph). You can use the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to see what the scraper sees when it hits your page.

Comment: oh, so you cannot use an image that is not in the link?

Comment: @Jeff Bowen, so what needs to be done on my side to make this link work? http://dailymus.es/images/d_logo.png

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue,  and the Debug tool isn't much help either

[video post with Youtube image (image 0 full)](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdonotargue.com%2Fvideo%2Fwacom-launches-cintiq-24hd-for-the-creative-professionals%2F)

[normal post with image](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdonotargue.com%2Fnote%2Fdice-responds-to-battlefield-3-leaked-footage%2F)

As you can see the pages are both valid according to the debug tool but I can not get any images to show on my webpage wall as well. It seem the OG standard is a bit flawed or the Facebook "crawler" isn't doing it's job. I know this isn't an answer but I just hope it will help as I see there's an " Developer Support team at Facebook" person in this topic.

Comment: not necessarily an answer, but does contribute toward a partial solution.. feel free to come back and edit this if you find out more